# Using Websecurity to manage users in WeAPI2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need someone to explain to me this very simple without shouting at me...i installed a webapi2 nuget to an empty mvc5 template. i did everything exelently, except one part where i tried to add simple-membership and didnt now where to begin...after weeks of googling, i found lots of content that helped me understand the following:

1. web administration tool doesn't support Simple-membership
2. Forms authentication and Simple-membership are different.

my quest is someone to atleast give me a clue on how to kick off using forms authentication with simple membership using webSecurity...like what do i need to install? what do i need to reference, and where? what classes do i need to inherit? where do i add authentication filters? or in simpler words, how do i make an empty MVC wepAPI template exercise the power of webSecurity like managing logins and logouts?
all tutorials i have read expect some basic knowledge on websecurity or simpleMembership, now i need all those basics first....

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recommend to you use the new ASP.NET Identity system, not the legacy membership provider.

Now you can secure your web api in different ways, But who is your API consumers? Are you building the API to be consumed by Mobile Apps? JS front-end apps? if this is the case then you can use token based authentication.

I've written very details and step by step tutorial on how tol build and secure the API using an empty template and you add the components you need only. Feel free to check it and let me know if you need further help. [Token Based Authentication Tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Comment: i looked at your article and one thing i understand is that i need to install ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework...i appreciate your response, i will try it out tomorrow morning